# Call to undefined function bf_b64dec() BREAZINGFORM in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have this problem with joomla breazingform where in the front part when calling a form I get the following error: Call to undefined function bf_b64dec()
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55Be5.png)

Any solution?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1IGT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding this code in the php file configuration from breezinf form:

```html
function bf_b64dec($data) {
    // Verificar si la entrada está codificada en base64 antes de decodificar
    if (base64_decode($data, true) !== false) {
        // Decodificar los datos en Base64 utilizando la función base64_decode()
        $decodedData = base64_decode($data);
        
        // Devolver el resultado decodificado
        return $decodedData;
    } else {
        // Si los datos no están en formato Base64 válido, devuelve un mensaje de error o maneja la situación adecuadamente
        return "Error: Los datos no están codificados en Base64 válidamente.";
    }
}
```